# The roman character to integer convertion function is not working properly

Tags: c++, string, roman-numerals

I am getting segmentation fault to this code to convert roman numerals to numbers, i am getting segmentation error when i try the program in  https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/online-compiler/ and i found that the inside of the loop A is never executed in my case

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

char str[50];
int a[50],m=50,val=0;

int intit(){
    m=strlen(str);

    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){//loop A
        cout<<i;
        if(str[i]=='M'){a[i]=1000;}
        if(str[i]=='D'){a[i]=500;}
        if(str[i]=='C'){a[i]=100;}
        if(str[i]=='L'){a[i]=50;}
        if(str[i]=='X'){a[i]=10;}
        if(str[i]=='V'){a[i]=5;}
        if(str[i]=='I'){a[i]=1;}
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    char str[50];
    int a[50],m,val=0;
    cin>>str;
    cout<<"exit val" +char(intit());
    for(int i=m-1;i>=0;i--){ //loop B
        cout<<"inside evaluation loop"<<a[i];
        if(a[i+1]>a[i]){val = val - a[i];}
        else{val = val + a[i];}
    }
    cout<<"\n\n\nans:"<<val;
    getch();
}
```

Comment: `char str[50];` is defined twice. The one that your `intit` function sees is the one defined globally. The one your `main` function sees is the one defined in main. Same with your other global variables.

Comment: You don't seem to realize that your global variables are different variables than the local variables of the same name in main().

Comment: You have defined variables `str`, `a`, `m`, and `val`  as global, and defined another set of them (unrelated to the globals, since they are in different scope) in `main()`.    Since `intit()` accesses the globals, nothing it does affects the variables in `main()`.    The simplest solution to that is to remove the declarations from `main()` - since that then causes `main()` to do things to the globals.   I haven't checked your code further, so there may be other problems as well, but getting the functions to work with the same data will be a start.

Comment: Im so sorry, i had the function inside main() previously and totally forgot about that another declaration in main(). Thank you so much.

Comment: Also, s is not initialized to zero, so you might run into garbage values.

Comment: ITS WORKING!, i removed the variable declaration inside the main(), its working for my inputs, have to check with ohter possible inputs. thank you so much

Comment: You might want to look into supplying the data to `intit()` as arguments, rather than relying on globals.    Globals will work in simple cases like this one, but they also come with a lot of constraints or "gotcha"s in practice - particularly if you start writing less simple code - so it is usually better to avoid globals where possible.

Answer (score 0):

You use **global** and **local** **variable** with the **same** **name**. remove one of them and the program work correctly.
However it is better to send your parameter by **reference** than define global parameter:

```
int intit(char (& str)[50], int (&a)[50],int &m ,int &val ) {
    m = strlen(str);

    for (int i = 0;i < m;i++) {//loop A
        cout << i;
        if (str[i] == 'M') { a[i] = 1000; }
        if (str[i] == 'D') { a[i] = 500; }
        if (str[i] == 'C') { a[i] = 100; }
        if (str[i] == 'L') { a[i] = 50; }
        if (str[i] == 'X') { a[i] = 10; }
        if (str[i] == 'V') { a[i] = 5; }
        if (str[i] == 'I') { a[i] = 1; }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    
    char str[50];
    int a[50], m = 50, val =0;
    cin >> str;
    cout << "exit val" + char(intit(str,a,m,val));
    for (int i = m - 1;i >= 0;i--) { //loop B
        cout << "inside evaluation loop" << a[i];
        if (a[i + 1] > a[i]) { val = val - a[i]; }
        else { val = val + a[i]; }
    }
    cout << "\n\n\nans:" << val;
    
}
```

Comment: I made some changes but i still need your help, i moved the "evaluation loop" and "getting the string from the user" to the intit(). The program works fine when i leave the variable initialization as global, but when i change it to local im getting wrong errors

Comment: @kirupashankarraman Try to initialize arrays in the function like this `char str[50] = {""}; int a[50] = {0}` .